# How Can I modified the Hosts field in android, Im working with xamarin forms in C#

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, host

I use Xamarin.forms and I need to modified the hosts file.
I am using Visual Studio 2019 and I need to block certain web pages of the smartphone, I work with Xamarin in android and the emulators that come by default in Visual Studio.

Comment: AFAIK this is not something an app can do.  See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/174515/how-to-edit-etc-hosts-file-in-non-rooted-phone

Comment: Another way to look at this is that the person who has physical possession of a device is the only one who *should* consider modifying the device at the system level - that is not  something that an app should be able to do. Perhaps explain more about *why* you want to do this - there might be an alternative way to approach your goal.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.